# meteor react material-ui Steppers

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, material-ui

So I'm using Meteor with React for a short while and i've seen, that there are steppers for material-ui on [googles material-ui specification site](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/steppers.html), but i found absolutely nothing about how to use it with Meteor! The interesting thing is, that i found some code in the node_modules/material-ui folder for those steppers.... Can someone tell me s.th. about this?

I'm using Meteor 1.3.1 with react@0.14.8 and material-ui@0.15.0-alpha.2..
other npm packages i have installed:
  -http
  -react-dom
  -react-mounter

Comment: I guess you would use it like described here: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui. Or do you have a Meteor-specific problem with material-ui?

Comment: I got no specific issue for this, but i would like to use those Steppers for my Meteor-project and i found no documentation which is describing how to use them or what functionality they provide although i found some code for them in my node_modules/material-ui folder....